# Sum of the series $\sinθ\sin2θ + \sin2θ\sin3θ + \sin3θ\sin4θ + \sin4θ\sin5θ + \cdots+\sin n\theta\sin(n+1)\theta$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is given:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sin (i\theta) \sin ((i+1)\theta)$$
 We have to find the sum to n terms of the given series.
 I could took out the $2\sin^2\cos$ terms common in the series. But what to do further, please guide me.

Comment: Use the formula –2 sin A sin B = cos (A + B) – cos (A – B) can simplify the arguement to certain extend.

Comment: Use de moivre theorem

Comment: well thats a good idea

Comment: I would beseech you to avoid using $i$ as index label for these kinds of series, since it's all too likely we might want to use that letter to denote the imaginary unit in the course of solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use

$$2 \sin{n \theta} \, \sin{(n+1) \theta} = \cos{\theta}-\cos{(2 n+1)\theta}$$

Then the sum is

$$\frac12 n \cos{\theta} - \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^n \cos{(2 n+1)\theta}$$

The sum may be done as follows:

$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^n \cos{(2 n+1)\theta} &= \operatorname{Re}{\left [e^{i \theta}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{i 2 k \theta}\right ]} \\ &=\operatorname{Re}{\left [e^{i 3 \theta} \frac{1-e^{i 2 n \theta}}{1-e^{i 2 \theta}}\right ]}\\ &= \operatorname{Re}{\left [e^{i (n+2) \theta} \frac{\sin{n \theta}}{\sin{\theta}}\right ]}\\ &= \frac{\sin{n \theta}}{\sin{\theta}} \cos{(n+2) \theta} \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint1:**

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sin (i\theta) \sin ((i+1)\theta)
=  1/2\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\cos (\theta)-\cos ((2i+1)\theta)\right)$$

**Hint2:**

$$ 2\sin (\theta)\sum_{i=1}^n \cos ((2i+1)\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sin ((2i+2)\theta) - \sin (2i\theta)\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For the part $A = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos (2i+1)x$, use:

$\sin x\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \cos (2i+1)x$, and expand each term you can see a telescope sum.